# NSURLErrorDomain (Code=-1012) while trying to get Uber auth token

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlerrordomain

I'm integrating Uber API into my app, using [UberKit](https://github.com/sachinkesiraju/UberKit).

Pressing my Login button calls `[uberKit startLogin];` having `clientID`, `clientSecret`, `applicationName`, `redirectURL` and `delegate` set.

After the app is back from Safari with authorization code, I cannot get authenticated token! It always fails in function `getAuthTokenForCode:` of `UberKit.m`:

```
Error in sending request for access token Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x16e7edf0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://login.uber.com/oauth/token, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://login.uber.com/oauth/token, NSUnderlyingError=0x16e7d600 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}
```

Could you advise what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have tried several times and it turned out you have to make sure that your app name registered on Uber developer site matches your app bundle identifier.

Comment: checked so many times but still getting same issue, any fix??